# TopoJSON: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'objects' of undefined

Tags: javascript, topojson

I am working on a project that is using TopoJSON. I cannot for the life of me figure out why I am getting this error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'objects' of undefined.
```

```js
//use queue to parallelize asynchronous data loading
var promises = []
promises.push(d3.csv("data/flood_data.csv")) //load attriutes from csv
promises.push(d3.json("data/states.topojson")) //load background spatial data
promises.push(d3.json("data/counties.topojson")) //load choropleth spatial data
Promise.all(promises).then(callback)

function callback(csvData, statesUS, countiesUS) {
  //place graticule on the map
  setGraticule(map, path)

  //translate states TopoJSON
  var usStates = topojson.feature(
      statesUS,
      statesUS.objects.cb_2018_us_state_5m
    ),
    usCounties = topojson.feature(countiesUS, countiesUS.objects.counties)
      .features
}
```

The error is in the last two lines in the above code. However, I know the data is there because when I checked if my data join worked, by csv has joined with my counties.topojson. I looking for any suggetions!

Comment: can you please update what is in stateUS ... the error means `there is no property named objects inside statesUS` it's clear

Comment: `console.log(statesUS)` inside callback